# Need someone who can explain me this code (Decimal to binary converter)

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
 function calculate() {
      var num = document.getElementById("decimal").value; //fetching binary value from html input box.
      var bin = [];
      while (num > 0) {
          bin[bin.length] = num % 2;
          num >>= 1; // basically /= 2 without remainder if any
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Binary Value: " + bin.reverse().join('');
}
</script>
```

I am trying to understand this code i can't understand these two lines in this code:

```
bin[bin.length] = num % 2;
num >>= 1;`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  bin[bin.length] = num % 2;
```

Append a 0 or 1 to `bin` depending on whether num is even or odd.

```
  num >>= 1;
```

As the comment says, this divides num by 2 without remainder.    Overall, the loop puts the digits of the binary representation of num into bin from least significant to most.  That is why it is reversed at the end.

Comment: i still dont understand how bin[bin.length] is auto incrementing the index value of bin?

Comment: You declare it as array so index increments like i++. If you declare is as var then try it.

Answer (score 0):

bin[bin.length] is just the index of the number (string,actually) that will be crated. For each bin.reverse() it increments by one. The num is a number in digital form.  num >>= 1 just shifts right 1 digits. This has an affect to divine the decimal by 2. bin[bin.length] = num % 2 just result to 0 or 1 and add each time to the string to form the final answer.
I am not sure which part you do not understand. Some operator or the whole logic?

Comment: i didnt understand the operators, thanks for your reply but i still dont understand how bin[bin.length] is auto incrementing the index value of bin?

Comment: I didn t explained it correctly. bin[bin.length] = num % 2 will add 0 or 1, right? so before teh loop bin[] is empty. At first iteration will be bin[0]=X (where X is 0 or 1). At SECOND iteration bin.length equals 1 now, not 0, because bin[] is not emty now. So again bin[1]= 0 or 1. At third iteration bin.length equals 3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how `bin[bin.length] = ...` puts the value in the correct spot. Well, bin starts as an empty array (`bin = []`) which has length 0. So `bin[bin.length] = bin[0]` to start and the first thing is inserted appropriately at index 0.

This `length` property is maintained internally as things are inserted into the array. So it will always insert in the first available slot.

Example: after something has been added at index 0, the `length` property is updated to 1 and the next insertion is done at `bin[bin.length]` which is equivalent to `bin[1]`.